# Web services after sprig boot update not working

Tags: spring-boot, web-services

I have a maven project that was based on spring boot 1.5.3.RELEASE. This project defines a web service and it runs fine.

After upgrading to spring boot 2.1.1.RELEASE and correcting compilation and dependency problems, the project starts, but the web service is not accessible. I get a HTTP 404 when trying to access. Below the response from SOAP UI:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=AFDD58540E3FBC88BA71073E136B7F3E; Path=/dx; HttpOnly
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 06 Jun 2019 13:30:40 GMT
```

Any ideas what changed in the new version that my web service is not available ? Thank you !

Comment: Without showing the relevant code that results in the 404 error, it's going to be difficult to help.

Comment: I would not know what code to show. The code should be OK. It works with spring boot 1. I suspect something in the configuration or the way a web service gets registered / published in the new version of spring boot.

Comment: For example, you could post a simple setup with Spring boot 2 that results in a 404 and that allows us to reproduce the problem. Additionally it would be useful if you posted your setup with Soap UI. For more information: [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Is there any error in logs?

If the error is like below:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
```

it is a `bouncycastle jar` conflict issue. You need to exclude the minor version of the jar.

Or you can use `http` web services instead of `https`.

Comment: Thank you, but no, there is no such error. There are actually no errors in the log. The only error I have is the 404 I get in SOAP UI.